# Frequency out of range

Tags: display, resolution, hdmi, vga, dvi

I bought LG 24" LED monitor (24MP47HQ) for my HP desktop (Elite 8200 SFF).
If I increase the resolution to 1600*1200 or 1920*1080, then it says 'Frequency out of range'
How can I increase the resolution to its maximum (1920*1080)?

They provided HDMI <-> DVI-D cable, but I connected desktop and monitor using D-SUB cable.

OS is Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit.

Comment: What type of video card are you using?  Onboard video or some sort of pci-x plugin card?

Comment: @Richie086 I believe it is PCI-X (AMD Radeon HD 6350)

Comment: Do you have the current amd catalyst drivers installed?

Comment: @Richie086 Yes, I think so. I installed graphic drivers from HP website and monitor driver from the CD that LG provided.

Comment: @Richie086 Might it be the cable problem? because I didn't use the cable that comes with the monitor..

Comment: See no Jay's answer below

Answer (score 2):

It's likely that the D-Sub connection on the monitor can't support the full resolution at 60Hz, the screen refresh rate most 1920*1080 monitors want to work at. I don't think the screen you have will work properly with 1600*1200 anyway -- if it did the image would be distorted as that's a 4:3 ratio and the monitor's panel is 16:9.

The Elite 8200SFF computer comes with only a DisplayPort output as standard, no HDMI connection or DVI-D. I presume you have a DisplayPort to D-Sub adaptor inline or a DP to D-sub cable you've been using on another display. You should try to get hold of a DisplayPort to HDMI cable and try that. They're not too expensive.

Comment: My graphic card has DMS-59 connector, so I connect it with the monitor using D-SUB cable.
The cable that came with the monitor has HDMI on one side and DVI-D on the other side and the monitor has only HDMI and D-SUB port. Thus the DVI-D side should go to the desktop. Then do I need Displayport-DVI-D adaptor?